# "Cannot read property 'fitBounds' of undefined" when plotting markers on Google Maps with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to have my map zoom or expand to fit all markers when it updates as some are plotted off the screen and you can't see them. My code is as follows...

```
$scope.loadMap = function () {
        var chosenDestination = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.destination.Latitude, $scope.destination.Longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: chosenDestination,
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        }

        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: chosenDestination,
            map: $scope.map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: $scope.destination.Name,
            labelContent: " ",
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 35),
            labelClass: "searchLocation" + $scope.destination.Name
        });
    }

    $scope.updateMapMarkers = function (hotel) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


        var createMarker = function (hotel) {
            var index = $scope.hotels.indexOf(hotel) + 1;


            var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(hotel.Location.Latitude, hotel.Location.Longitude);


            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                map: $scope.map,
                position: LatLng,
                title: hotel.title,
                labelContent: index,
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 35),
                labelClass: "mapLabels",
                labelInBackground: false
            });

            bounds.extend(LatLng);

            marker.content = '<div style=\'width:250px\'>' + hotel.Address + '</div>';

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
                infoWindow.setContent('content goes here');
                infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                $scope.markerId = $scope.markers.indexOf(marker);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
                infoWindow.close($scope.map, marker);
            });

            $scope.markers.push(marker);

            $scope.map.fitBounds(bounds);

        }

        for (i = $scope.plottingStartPoint; i < $scope.hotels.length; i++) {
            createMarker($scope.hotels[i])
        }


    }

    $scope.loadMap();
    $scope.updateMapMarkers();
```

I am getting the error **Cannot read property 'fitBounds' of undefined**. When I debug it $scope.map at that point is undefined although it works when just plotting markers, it just fails when it comes to 'fitBounds'.

If I remove the code that sets the bounds then everything works fine.

Anyone know what I may have done wrong here? Still learning AngularJS so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a new (different) scope is being created in `updateMapMarkers()` and the 'map' property is being called on that scope and not on your original scope. Make sure that you are referencing the same scope for both function call. Try providing a proper model maybe(?):

```
$scope.model = { map: undefined };
```